# Dockerfile not copying images folder to node-red directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, copy

I want to copy some pictures to a folder in the node-red image, however it doesn't seem to work even though other `COPY` commands work.

```
FROM nodered/node-red AS base

USER root

COPY package.json /data/

COPY flows.json /data/
COPY img/ /data/
COPY new_settings.js /data/settings.js


CMD ["npm", "start", "--cache", "/data/.npm", "--", "--userDir", "/data", "--settings new_settings.js"]
```

The `img/` is in the same directory as the other files that I copy, `new_settings.js` and `flows.json`. The logs don't report any error but everytime I go and check if the files are there, they are nowhere to be found.

This is my folder hierachy:

```
- node-red
  + img
  Dockerfile
  flows.json
  new_settings.js
  package.json
```

To check if the files are there, I am using docker Desktop which allows me to go directly to the CLI of the image. There I access the data folder by running the command `cd /data/` and then `ls` to see all files.

Comment: Please edit your post and add how you check if the files are there.

Comment: Do you have any volumes mapped to the container when you run it? If you do, what path(s) are they mapped to?

Comment: @HansKilian I only have one volume mapped which is node-red-data:/data n my docker-compose file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map a volume to `/data` like you do, you hide everything in the image in that path and replace it with whatever is in the volume you map to it.

To see the data in the image, you can't map a volume to `/data`.

For more info, see the second bullet point here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/#tips-for-using-bind-mounts-or-volumes

Comment: The folder is now created but I can't seem to access it on node-red. Shouldn't the path be just the name of the directory?

Comment: I don't know anything about node-red :(